# Создаю класс для работы с бинарными потоками для записи обьектов в файл,но при считывании вылетает StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, io

Знаю что уже были такие вопросы,но прочитав все так и не смог понять проблему.

```
 java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readBlockHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
at ua.TaskIO.readBinary(TaskIO.java:80)
at ua.Main.main(Main.java:70)
```

Вот привожу пример моего кода для записи и считывания из файла

```
public void writeBinary(TaskList tasks, File file) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream writeObject = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            writeObject.writeObject(tasks.getTask(i));
            writeObject.flush();
        }
        writeObject.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readBinary(TaskList tasks, File file) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream readObject = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        while (readObject.available() > -1) {
            Task task = (Task) readObject.readObject();
            tasks.add(task);
        }
        readObject.close();
        System.out.println("good");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

И метод main

```
TaskIO io = new TaskIO();
File file = new File("text.dat");
io.writeBinary(newT, file);
io.writeBinary(b, file);
ArrayTaskList list = new ArrayTaskList();
io.readBinary(list, file);
```

Comment: Я находил много аналогичных вопросов,но не могу понять где я повторно вызываю ObjectOutputStream, что оно перезаписывает header на 0xAC

Comment: Вы два раза вызываете `writeBinary`,  а там `new ObjectOutputStream(..)` во второй строке. Проблема в том, что оно пишет заголовок каждый раз, и при чтении второго объекта `ObjectInputStream` ожидает увидеть код типа следующей записи, а видит `AC` и останавливается.

Comment: В качестве альтернативы можете попробовать перед `readObject.readObject()` начиная со второго вызов делать `readObject.readInt()`, чтобы пропустить 4 байта лишнего заголовка.

Comment: Понял ошибку.спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `available` возвращает количество доступных в данный момент для чтения байт. С условием `readObject.available() > -1` чтение осуществляется даже когда читать нечего (доступное количество байт равно 0).

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю сохранить количество объектов в потоке.

```
public void writeBinary(TaskList tasks, File file) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream writeObject = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
        writeObject.writeInt(tasks.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.size(); i++) {
            writeObject.writeObject(tasks.getTask(i));
        }
        writeObject.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void readBinary(TaskList tasks, File file) {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream readObject = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        int count = readObject.readInt();
        for (int i =0; i < count; i++) {
            Task task = (Task) readObject.readObject();
            tasks.add(task);
        }
        readObject.close();
        System.out.println("good");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

PS: Не нужно вызывать `flush` после сохранения каждого объекта. Это только замедляет запись.

Comment: Сделал через DataInputStream/outputStream.Пытался записывать к-ство но считывание не происходило.